# How to change the Lease state of Azure Blob to Available

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I have an Azure storage account, and there is a blob in container. I clicked on acquire lease on that blob and the Lease state got changed from **Available** to **Leased**. Now I want to revert it back to **Available**. I clicked on **Break Lease** hoping it will revert the state to **Available**, but it changed the state to **Broken**

Now, the Lease state is changing between **Leased** and **Broken**, But I am not able to revert it to **Available** state. Any help on how to revert the lease state to **Available**?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do what you want by using the Azure Portal.

A lease can only be cleanly released by using the lease id that was returned during the original lease operation.

You can change the lease state to **available** manually by leasing and releasing the blob using Azure CLI, or any other SDK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/lease?view=azure-cli-latest

```
$leaseId=az storage blob lease acquire -b myblob -c mycontainer --account-name mystorageaccount --account-key 0000-0000
az storage blob lease release --lease-id $leaseId -b myblob -c mycontainer --account-name mystorageaccount --account-key 0000-0000
```

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-container-lease for more general documentation.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I am able to revert the lease state to Available using Azure CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with a container. The solution is similar, with slightly different commands.

Here they are for PowerShell:

To acquire the lease:

```
$leaseId=az storage container lease acquire --account-name mystorageaccount --container-name mycontainer --account-key 0000-0000
```

To release the lease:

```
az storage container lease release --lease-id $leaseId --account-name mystorageaccount --container-name mycontainer --account-key 0000-0000
```